# How to remove the first and last elements of a list and return the list without those elements?

Tags: python

I have a function middle(c) that accepts as input a list c and outputs the list c and the problem that I need to solve is outputting this list without the first and last elements. My code is below.

```
    def middle(c):
     del c[0]
     del c[-1]
     return middle(c)
```

It gives me this after running the code
Exception "list assignment index out of range"
I had some similar problems where I returned c[0] to find the first element of the list which worked so maybe the problem is with the return statement?

Comment: `return c[1:-1]` ?

Comment: You've made a recursive function. It will keep calling itself until the list runs out of items.

Comment: Admittedly the error message is rather misleading. I don't think `del` is a "list assignment".

Comment: In your own words,where you have written `return middle(c)`, what do you think that means? How are you expecting it to help you solve the problem? After `del c[0]` and `del c[-1]` happen, what are you expecting `c` to look like? How does that compare to the value you want to `return` from the function? Therefore, what should the last line look like instead?

Comment: Separately: what does "without the first and last elements" mean for a list that was already empty? What does it mean for a list that only had one element?

Comment: Well, have you seen that the CPU usage spikes when running this program? That's a problem. (If not, use a desktop gadget to see the CPU usage.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to pull everything from index 1 to -1.

```py
def middle(c):
    return c[1:-1]
```

## Edit

Originally in my answer  I incorrectly stated that c[1::-1] would result in an `IndexError` if `c` had a length of 0 or 1. This is because slicing a list does not actually pull each element at each index, as I expected.

Slicing can be more appropriately described as checking to see if an index exists and then pulling the value for the resulting slice. So in the expression `[][1::]` python attempts to take a slice of every element from the list but the first. When no element is found that satisfies that, none is added to the resultant list and no IndexError` is thrown.

Comment: I think you mean `[1:-1]`, not `[1::-1]`.

Comment: @joshmeranda slicing does not throw any Index Error. It pretty much ignores the empty list.

Comment: @PCM I understand that, which is why I updated my answer with a simplified explanation as to why my original answer, which contained an incorrect statement, was partially incorrect

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `del`, use `.pop` method -

```
def middle(c):
  c.pop() # Removes last element
  c.pop(0) # Removes first element
  return c

c = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

print(middle(c)) # [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

The problem in your code was that it did not return the list, but it returned the function `middle`, so it is gonna be a `recursive` function and it will keep deleting until all elements get deleted. Then you get `list assignment index out of range`. So change your code to -

```
def middle(c):
     del c[0]
     del c[-1]
     return c
```

Comment: `del` can delete the whole list accidentally. So I used `.pop`. OP can choose what to use.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this could be with list slicing. What is list slicing? Well, it is a method of accessing a **range** of values. The way to slice is a list is below. Assume my_list is a sample list.

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
my_list[1:-1] # Returns the list starting from element at index 1 (i.e. the second element) 
# and ends  element at index -1 (i.e. the last element)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to "return the list", which to me sounds like you don't want a copied slice:

```
def middle(c):
    del c[:1]       # Safely delete the first element (if there is one)
    del c[-1:]      # Safely delete the last element (if there is one)
    return c        # Return the list, don't call it recursively to remove more
```